# Azure Devops Dashboard Widget Display Comma Separated Field as Individual Values

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, widget

I have Team-Defined Data for our work-items and one of the user-inputted Text fields (TextE) is comma separated as such:

TextE: x,y,z

Is there a way to parse this column using comma delimiter and display the values as individual items in a widget (ex. as a pie graph)?

For example for 3 work items we may have:

Work item 1 TextE: apples,oranges,banana

Work item 2 TextE: apples,oranges

Work item 3 TextE: apples,banana

What I am looking for is the pie chart counts 3 apples, 2 oranges and 2 bananas and NOT treat it as 1 "apples,oranges,banana", 1 "apples,oranges", 1 "apples,banana".

Does Azure Devops have this type of capability?